# mysql: copy row & change one value, if doesn't exist with one value difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to copy a set of rows from a MySQL table into the same table. I already have the sql query to copy the rows, change one value and update the primary key (auto_increment). But my question is I'd like to only perform this when there's no row (with another condition), that has the same value for a certain column of the origin row.

For Example:

```
{ID, USER_ID, VALUE_A, VALUE_B}
```

Copy all rows where USER_ID is "USER_A" and there's no row where USER_ID is "USER_B" and VALUE_A is VALUE_A from original row; In these copied rows auto_increment ID and set USER_ID to "USER_B"

Comment: Please add your query so that we can show you how to do that.

Comment: `insert into table (user_id, value_a, value_b)
select 'USER_B', value_a, value_b from table where user_id = 'USER_A';` (ID is not specified = auto_increment)

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is select rows that does not already exists. One way to achieve that is left join and retrieve records that doesn't have a match. Something like this:

```
insert int table (user_id, value_a, value_b)
select * from (
    select t1.user_id, t1.value_a, t1.value_b
    from table t1 
    left join table t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
    and t1.value_a = t2.value_a
    and t1.value_b = t2.value_b
    where t2.value_a is null and t2.value_b is null
) as t
```